# The column exists but cannot be saved

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-5.8

The column exists but cannot be saved
**index.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{route('work.store', ['id' => $param->id])}}" method="post">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="{{$param->id}}">
```

**WorkController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request,$id)
{
    $work = new Work;
    $work->fill($request->all())->save();
    return redirect()->route('workindex', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

**create_work_table.php**

```
    Schema::create('work', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('project_id');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->time('work_time');
        $table->string('input_person');
        $table->timestamp('input_date');

        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/work/{id}', 'WorkController@store')->name('work.store');
```

Exists but does not exist

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table category has no column named project_id (SQL: insert into "category" ("project_id", "input_person", "input_date", "user_id", "estimated_work_time", "content", "updated_at", "created_at") values (4, 1, 2019-08-30 08:02:19, 1, 02:00, hoge, 2019-08-30 08:52:15, 2019-08-30 08:52:15))
```

Comment: Why you are passing `project_id` in hidden?? you're already sending in action parameter. Remove `project_id` input hidden.

Comment: Have you added the project_id field to the $fillable property of the Work model?

Comment: @DilipHirapara Because I want to pass only the ID to Route.

Comment: @dparoli I forgot
Thank you so much

Comment: `<form action="{{route('work.store', ['id' => $param->id])}}" method="post">` you're passing it in action as well right? The error is because you use fill method and passing project_id in form so fill method try to finding project_id in works table and it's not exist. That's why you are getting the error. And now if you want to redirect the same page then you may `use return redirect()->back()->with('success', ['your message,here']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your table name is wrong

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table category has no column named project_id (SQL: insert into "category"
```

Insert into category but you have created table name work.

Comment: I forgot to add it to fillable　Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table have **project_id**.

Or make sure in your model it should be fillable.

```
protected $fillable = [
        'project_id'
    ];
```